# how android choose resource folders for different api levels

Tags: android, api, resources, directory

My app has layout-v21 folder for Android 5.0. Do API22 and API23 devices use layouts in this folder or the from the default layout folder?

How does Android choose API specific resources?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Do API22 and API23 devices use layouts in this folder

Yes, unless there is a `layout-v22` or `layout-v23` directory. `layout-v21` says to use that directory for API Level 21 and higher.